# How can I use the MailKit ImapClient to read messages while it is in idle state?

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mime, mailkit

I'm using `IdleAsync` to get notified about new emails.

I want to get notified whenever a new message arrives and then read the message, but when I try to read the message, I am getting an exception that `ImapClient` is in idle state.

Do I need create another `ImapClient` or can we use the same client to read the message without stopping receiving notifications of new messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nameless One has noted, MailKit's Idle() and IdleAsync() methods take a "done" CancellationToken which can be used to end the IDLE state (when you cancel the "done" token, it will send the DONE command thus ending the IDLE state).

Once you've done that, you can fetch messages and continue on as normal.

The other option, which some people do, is to have 2 ImapClients - one being used to Idle() and the other used for fetching messages.

Comment: I'm confused, when we cancel the "done" token we can fetch the messages but we will no longer can get new mails notification(as idle state is exited). is this right? So the only way(which i'm using right now) is to use two IMAP clients. One for getting new mails(Idle) and other for fetching mails. Also I have one more doubt when IMAP client is in Idle state, will we get any uid or something for a newly arrived mail so that we can fetch that message using that id. Right now i'm using folder.Count-1 to read the first mail.

Comment: Correct, when you cancel the doneToken, you will stop getting notifications for new messages, but you can call Idle() again after you fetch the new messages.

Comment: When new messages arrive, you will *not* get a UID (because the server does not send one) for the new message(s), so you'll have to do what you are already doing.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I will better use two IMAP clients

Answer (score 2):

In IDLE state the only command you can send is DONE which terminates IDLE.  You might consider using CONDSTORE and detecting new messages using HIGHESTMODSEQ if you don't mind polling.

Comment: I'm supposed to use MailKit only. So i'm looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rick Sanders is right, that you need to Send the `DONE` response (see [RFC2177](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) for how IMAP `IDLE` and `DONE` work).

Although I am not familiar with mailkit, or [Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.100).aspx) it looks like the [Idle](https://jstedfast.github.io/MailKit/docs/MailKit.Net.Imap/ImapClient.html#M:MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.Idle(System.Threading.CancellationToken,System.Threading.CancellationToken)) method accepts a  `CancellationToken` which you can cancel by calling `Cancel()` on its `CancellationTokenSource`. This should then send the `DONE` command as needed.

Comment: You are correct, when the doneToken is cancelled, it will send the DONE command, exiting the IDLE state. I'll update the docs to mention this.